# What makes this Angular file uploader fail when browsing for the file?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

I am working on an app in Angular 14 with includes a form. The form has a **file uploader**.

In `form.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormService } from '../services/form.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
})
export class FormComponent {
  @ViewChild('fileDropRef', { static: false })
  public fileDropEl!: ElementRef;
  public files: any[] = [];

  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    imageName: new FormControl(''),
  });

  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  // File uploader Begin
  public onFileDropped($event: any) {
    this.prepareFilesList($event);
  }

  public fileBrowseHandler(files: any) {
    this.prepareFilesList(files);
  }

  public deleteFile(index: number) {
    if (this.files[index].progress < 100) {
      console.log('Upload in progress.');
      return;
    }
    this.files.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public uploadFilesSimulator(index: number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (index === this.files.length) {
        return;
      } else {
        const progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
          if (this.files[index].progress === 100) {
            clearInterval(progressInterval);
            this.uploadFilesSimulator(index + 1);
          } else {
            this.files[index].progress += 5;
          }
        }, 200);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  public prepareFilesList(files: Array<any>) {
    for (const item of files) {
      item.progress = 0;
      this.files.push(item);
    }
    this.fileDropEl.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.uploadFilesSimulator(0);
  }

  public formatBytes(bytes: number, decimals: number = 2) {
    if (bytes === 0) {
      return '0 Bytes';
    }
    const k = 1024;
    const dm = decimals <= 0 ? 0 : decimals;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }
  // File uploader End

  public sendFormData() {
    this.formService
      .sendFormData(this.formService.value)
      .subscribe((response) => {});
  }
}
```

In the template, the file uploader looks like this:

```
<div class="file-uploader-container">
  <div class="file-uploader" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
    <input formControlName="imageName" type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple />
    <div class="center">
      <h3 class="upload">Drop your file to upload</h3>
      <h3 class="upload text-center">or</h3>
      <label class="btn-label" for="fileDropRef">Browse for file</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="files-list">
    <div class="single-file" *ngFor="let file of files; let i = index">
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/dnd/ic-file.svg"
        alt=""
        class="file-icon"
      />
      <div class="info">
        <p class="name">{{ file?.name }}</p>
        <p class="size">{{ formatBytes(file?.size) }}</p>
        <app-progress [progress]="file?.progress"></app-progress>
      </div>
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/dnd/ic-delete-file.svg"
        class="delete"
        width="20px"
        alt="file"
        (click)="deleteFile(i)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a Stackblitz **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-dguv1w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts)**.

#### The problem

Although the file uploader works as expected when the user drags a file over it, displaying the *upload progress*, it *fails when browsing* for the file.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

salutare:) you need to trigger "onFileDropped" also  in file selection:

```js
   <input #inputType type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="onFileChange($event)"/>

onFileChange(event: any) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    this.onFileDropped(files);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-nwwixu?file=src/app/form/form.component.html

Comment: When I do `console.log(this.form.value)`, for the `imageName` field I get `C:\\fakepath\\test.png`. Why? How do I get the filename only? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give where you want to get it?

Comment: I want to set te value of `<input formControlName="imageName" type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple />` to the file name (instead of the full path to the file).

Comment: I think you cannot set input linked to that form control, this input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string. When you will use those values, you could trim unnecessary chars. You could use a regex: const filePath = 'C:\\fakepath\\test.png';
const fileName = filePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
console.log(fileName); // Output: test.png

Comment: Where do you want to use that value?